# Fibonacci Series is not working

Tags: javascript, html

This code is returning 1, how to solve this issue. I'm not able to fix this issue.. Any ideas ?

```js
function fibonacci() {
  var i;
  var fib = [];
  fib[0] = 0;
  fib[1] = 1;
  for (i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
    fib[i] = fib[i - 2] + fib[i - 1];
    return (fib[i]);
  }
}

alert(fibonacci());
```

Comment: You're returning inside the loop, so you never repeat the loop.

Comment: Move the return outside the loop

Comment: when i return outside the loop then it gives me undefined msg

Comment: `return (fib)` <-

Comment: It gives you undefined because `i` gets incremented to 11, so return fib[10] or fib[i - 1]

Comment: thanks .. return (fib) is fix

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can minimise the code and do something like:

```js
function fibonacci() {
  for (var n = [0, 1], r = 2; r <= 10; r++)
    n[r] = n[r - 2] + n[r - 1];
  return n
}

console.log(fibonacci());
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your return out and just return the array

```js
function fibonacci() {
  var i;
  var fib = []; 
  fib[0] = 0;
  fib[1] = 1;
  
  for (i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
    fib[i] = fib[i - 2] + fib[i - 1];
  }
  return fib;
}

alert(fibonacci());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function fibonacci() {
    var i;
    var fib = [];
    fib[0] = 0;
    fib[1] = 1;
    for (i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
        fib[i] = fib[i - 2] + fib[i - 1];
    }
    return (fib);
}
alert(fibonacci());
```

Comment: code like this should have an explanation of why it fixes the problem the OP was having.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

You want to make sure you dont return from the function inside the loop. Move the return line outside the loop but still within the function.

```js
function fibonacci() {
                var i;
                var fib = []; 
                fib[0] = 0;
                fib[1] = 1;
                for (i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
                    fib[i] = fib[i - 2] + fib[i - 1];
                }
                return fib;
}

alert(fibonacci());
```